# django-admin startproject my_site problem in vscode

Tags: django, django-admin

when i am typing command in cmd **django-admin startproject my_site** it is giving this error please help me universe. I tried everything from installing all to uninstalling all and it is not working and hinderancing my progress to become a web developer.

when i am typing command in cmd **django-admin startproject my_site** it is giving this error please help me universe. I tried everything from installing all to uninstalling all and it is not working and hinderancing my progress to become a web developer.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\chayan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\timezone.py", line 10, in <module>
    import zoneinfo
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zoneinfo'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\chayan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\chayan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\CHAYAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\Scripts\django-admin.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\chayan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "c:\users\chayan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "c:\users\chayan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 279, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "c:\users\chayan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 48, in load_command_class
    module = import_module("%s.management.commands.%s" % (app_name, name))
  File "c:\users\chayan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1021, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 998, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 977, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 789, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\users\chayan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\startproject.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.core.management.templates import TemplateCommand
  File "c:\users\chayan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\templates.py", line 16, in <module>
    from django.template import Context, Engine
  File "c:\users\chayan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    from .engine import Engine
  File "c:\users\chayan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\engine.py", line
7, in <module>
    from .base import Template
  File "c:\users\chayan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 59, in <module>
    from django.utils.formats import localize
  File "c:\users\chayan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\formats.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.utils import dateformat, numberformat
  File "c:\users\chayan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\dateformat.py", line 26, in <module>
    from django.utils.timezone import (
  File "c:\users\chayan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\timezone.py", line 12, in <module>
    from backports import zoneinfo
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'backports'
```

Comment: try this: `django-admin.py startproject mysite`

Comment: this showing                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                             
'django-admin.py' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: window 7 old one

Comment: please help me. @DivyaPrakash

Comment: please help me. @oruchkin

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are not using a virtual environment. Use the following commands to install virtual env.

```
pip install virtualenv
```

then you have to create a virtual environment, you can do that by following the command here.

```
python -m virtualenv myEnv # ---> whatever name you want here
```

and then you have to activate the environment by following command:

```
myEnv\Scripts\activate
```

and to deactivate, simply use:

```
deactivate
```